# Openshift can't find my css file

Tags: html, css, openshift

I managed to create a new app on Openshift and the basic template that they provided me with is working. The only thing I added to it is:

```
<head>
...
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

and a file styles.css in the same directory as index.html. In the css file I just changed the footer to red. When I click on index.html my browser shows the changes, but when I upload the files to Openshift nothing changes and I get:

```
GET http://bgl-boardgamelab.rhcloud.com/styles.css 404 (Not Found)
```

I think I'm making some silly mistake, but can't figure what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had to add the following to my `.initializeServer` function to serve all my static files:

```
self.app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer and also thanks this really helped!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Comment: try with absolute path

Answer (score 0):

Try full path url like:

```
<link href="http://localhost/myproject/styles.css">
```

or

```
<link href="http://examplesite.com/styles.css">
```

Comment: The folder where I keep all the docs and files is called bgl and the website is: http://bgl-boardgamelab.rhcloud.com. So here's what I tried: <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://bgl-boardgamelab.rhcloud.com/bgl/styles.css' type='text/css'> did not work and <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://bgl-boardgamelab.rhcloud.com/styles.css' type='text/css'> did not work as well. (I used http:// as well but for some reason it doesn't show here on stackoverflow)